# how to find using regular expression in field with keyword like below

Tags: elasticsearch

I have record with field as below  "CASE_NUMBER": "I-200-17258-418385" and want to do regular expression search using query string like

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*58\\-41*",
            "default_operator": "and",
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "fields": [
              "CASE_NUMBER"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
```

It is not returning any results but if I search for *41* then it does return results

What shall I change ?

Comment: what does your ES mapping look like?

Comment: text and keyword for this field do I need to add custom analyzer ?

Comment: if I search \*17258\\-418385\* then I am getting results

Comment: Have you tried your `query_string` search using the `"CASE_NUMBER.keyword"` field?

Comment: yes it worked thanks, i though keyword is only for exact match , if I have to search using CASE_NUMBER only do I need to add custom analyzer ? what should be criteria

Comment: if I am right it is not reg exp , it is wildcard query as for reg exp it should be enclosed by / /